# Why doesn't the compiler complain when I assign true to an int variable?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

I have a program that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "string.h"
#include <sstream>

class A{
    int num1;
    char char1;

    public:
        void set_print_num(int);
};

void A::set_print_num(int n){
    num1 = true;
    printf("this is %d", num1);
}

int main(void){
    A a_inst;
    a_inst.set_print_num(5);
}
```

I don't get a compiler error even though I have set num1 to true instead of to an int. Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

All of your variables retain their types.  A value of one type may be converted to another type, however.

`true` is a value of type `bool`, which is implicitly convertible to type `int`, with the value `false` becoming `0` and the value `true` becoming `1`.

There are many implicit conversions in C++, most of which allow conversions between numeric types, and it is possible to write user-defined conversions, to allow implicit conversions to and from user-defined types.

Answer (score 1):

A `bool` is implicitly convertible to an `int`. Raise your warning level and you should get one, but not an error as this is legal *C++*.

Answer (score 0):

because boolean types are implicitly converted to integer types. true + true for example evaluates to 2.